# Apache Pig Permission denied

Tags: linux, hadoop, apache-pig

I have installed pig on red hat linux virtual box. I followed all the instructions as mentioned in [**docs**](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/setup.html). I exacted the folder in `/usr/local/pig-0.17.0` folder but when I execute pig command it throws an error :

`-bash: /usr/local/pig-0.17.0/bin/pig: Permission denied`

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/pig-0.17.0/bin/*`...